# How to use @dev in project root when a package requires ^1.0

Tags: php, composer-php

In my dev project `composer.json` I have:

```
"require": {
    "bastinald/laravel-automatic-migrations": "@dev",
    "bastinald/laravel-bootstrap-forms": "@dev",
    "bastinald/laravel-livewire-routes": "@dev",
    "bastinald/livewire-bootstrap-auth": "@dev"
},
```

They are all added as repositories from the filesystem and symlinked so I can work on them within this project. I use this project to develop all of my own packages.

In one of my projects (`bastinald/livewire-bootstrap-auth`), I have this `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    "bastinald/laravel-automatic-migrations": "^1.0",
    "bastinald/laravel-bootstrap-forms": "^1.0",
    "bastinald/laravel-livewire-routes": "^1.0",
},
```

This is causing the following error:

```
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

    Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires bastinald/livewire-bootstrap-auth dev-master -> satisfiable by bastinald/livewire-bootstrap-auth[dev-master].
    - bastinald/livewire-bootstrap-auth dev-master requires bastinald/laravel-automatic-migrations ^1.0 -> satisfiable by bastinald/laravel-automatic-migrations[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3] from composer repo (https://repo.packagist.org) but bastinald/laravel-automatic-migrations[dev-master] from path repo (packages/bastinald/laravel-automatic-migrations) has higher repository priority. The packages with higher priority do not match your constraint and are therefore not installable. See https://getcomposer.org/repoprio for details and assistance.
```

I need to keep `^1.0` inside of my package json file for when it gets released. How do I make it so that I can still use `@dev` for all the packages in my development project, while using released versions inside the package composer.json files? Also, I want to make sure the packages used by other packages use `@dev` while in the dev project.

Is this possible? Or should I just switch the version from `@dev` back to `^1.0` before pushing a release like I have been?

Answer (score 0):

Use `dev-master as 1.0` as version, for example in your case:

```
"require": {
    "bastinald/laravel-automatic-migrations": "dev-master as 1.0",
    "bastinald/laravel-bootstrap-forms": "dev-master as 1.0",
    "bastinald/laravel-livewire-routes": "dev-master as 1.0",
    "bastinald/livewire-bootstrap-auth": "dev-master as 1.0"
},
```